# List Control Delete Row on Delete Key press

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a List Control holding rows with data. Now i am trying to delete row on delete key press. I am trying with : LVN_DELETEITEM as below :

Afx Message :

```
afx_msg void OnLvnDeleteitemList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
```

Message Map:

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_DELETEITEM, IDC_LIST_ACQUISITION_SETTINGS, &MeasureDialog::OnLvnDeleteitemList)
```

Implementation of OnLvnDeleteitemList :

```
void MeasureDialog::OnLvnDeleteitemList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
  LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
  ReportMessage(L"Deleted");
  *pResult = 0;
}
```

But i am never coming into the OnLvnDeleteitemList method. Whats wrong about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message [LVN_DELETEITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774812(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly states that:

> Notifies a list-view control's parent window that an item is about to be deleted.

Which means, when item is deleted, the notification message will be sent. Pressing the delete key won't invoke this method. You need to handle Delete key message itself ([WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx)), and call [`CListCtrl::DeleteItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84fyba4z.aspx)